# Import and Environment Variable issues using Python/Django in PYcharm on Ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, ubuntu-10.04, pycharm

I am working through the PYcharm tutorial, which sets up a polling site, as my first Python/Django project. I am new to this so if I am asking silly questions I apologize in advance. In the admin.py file the following import is not working:

```
from MyDjangoApp.polls.models import Poll, Choice
```

I have specified the environment variable as I found in other posts to

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE  MyDjangoApp.settings
```

with MyDjangoApp being my project name and MyDjangoApp.settings as the value in the Edit Configurations tab.

I also tried to follow the lightbulb suggestion to install package models but when I do that I get the following error:

```
Error occurred when installing packages.

The following command was executed:

packaging_tool.py install --build-dir /tmp/pycharm packaging1986982253689628475.tmp
models

The error output of the command:


Downloading/unpacking models
  Downloading models-0.9.3.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package models
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging1986982253689628475.tmp/models/setup.py", line 25, in
 <module>
    import models
  File "models/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from props import *
  File "models/props.py", line 23, in <module>
    import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging1986982253689628475.tmp/models/setup.py", line 25, in
<module>

import models

File "models/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>

from props import *

File "models/props.py", line 23, in <module>

import yaml

ImportError: No module named yaml

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pycharm
-packaging1986982253689628475.tmp/models
Storing complete log in /home/andrew/.pip/pip.log
```

I am not sure how to proceed. I have seen a decent amount of suggestions but they either don't work or I'm not doing it correctly. If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it. I have been banging my head against this wall most of the day today and I would really like to be able to move forward. Thanks is advance for anyone willing to help out a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

In `polls/admin.py` do `from models import Poll, Choice` - this is presuming you have a `models.py` file next to `admin.py`.